# Storing access token from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am planning to write an Azure Function that will communicate to DocuSign through DocuSign API. 
I am using JWT for authentication and what I am worried about is storing the Access Token.

The access token expires in 1 hour. As the Azure function is stateless, I have to put the access token somewhere to reuse it.

My question is about securely storing this token in Azure. 
I think the below services from Azure can serve me

- KeyVault
- Memchaed
- Azure Caching
- Azure SQL

Which will be best? I do not want an expensive service to serve this purpose.

Comment: why do you need to store it? I believe it should not be stored for safety reasons.

Comment: As @ThiagoCustodio pointed out, I don't think you should be storing it. But, having said that, I have come across apps that cache the token in browser storage

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to store the token, you can use KeyVault to realize your ideas. The communication between the resources in KeyVault and Azure is based on the Azure backbone network, so as long as Azure is safe, then KeyVault is safe. And, KeyVault was originally designed to acheive your current requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use redis ( or maybe DB for your case is easier/better )
Azure has redis, you can simply use that.

And why not Azure Key Vault ?
Look at docs:

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/secrets-best-practices)

```
Secrets, managed storage account keys, and vault transactions:
Transactions type   Maximum transactions allowed in 10 seconds, per vault per region1
All transactions    4,000
```

its because of transactions limits. You should not hit Azure KV so often.

Also interesting quote:

> Cache secrets in your application for at least eight hours.

About redis, you can read it here: [DocsRedis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/token-cache)

> The app uses a Redis cache as the backing store

[tutorial](https://developer.redis.com/create/azurefunctions/)